# sympyのsubsの使い方を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
var('RA,RAv,RB',real=True)
rep  ={RA:RAv}            ;print("# ",rep)
rep |={RB:RA.subs(rep)}   ;print("# ",rep)
#  {RA: RAv}
#  {RA: RAv, RB: RA}
```

以下にする方法を教えて下さい。
{RA: RAv, RB: RAv}

Comment: 「`subs`の使い方」という点だけなら, (回答にも出てるけど) 例えば `expr = x**2 + y + 1` の式が与えられるとき, `expr.subs({x: 10})` での結果は `y + 101` になるし, `expr.subs({x: 1, y: 2})` では `4` という結果になります。大抵はそのような使い方

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sympyのsubsの使い方を教えて下さい。

### 式のsubsメソッドの使い方

- 使用方法
  式.subs(引数)
- 振る舞い
  引数で指定された「置換される式」と「置換後の式」を使用して「式」中の「置換される式」を「置換後の式」に置換する。
- 「置換される式」と「置換後の式」は次のように指定する。

  - 「置換される式」と「置換後の式」は「置換される式」,「置換後の式」のタプル
  - キーが「置換される式」、値が「置換後の式」の辞書
  - 複数の置換を行う場合は置換される式」と「置換後の式」のタプルまたは辞書をリストで指定する。

---

```
rep |={RB:RA.subs(rep)}   ;print("# ",rep)
```

の結果は

```
#  {RA: RAv, RB: RA}
```

ではなく、意図どおり

```
#  {RA: RAv, RB: RAv}
```

になっています。

---

> 以下にする方法を教えて下さい。
> {RA: RAv, RB: RAv}

subsを使う必要はなく

```
rep[RB] = RAv
```

でよいです。